# Why does my program generate a list indexing issue?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm really new to programming and am trying to create a battleships game using Pygame. My game features and AI vs a player and currently I am struggling on how to put the AI's bombs into place. I've created a function(`bombs`) that sets the `grid[row][column]` to `2`, where it'll output "Boom" if clicked. It works if I set and individual value to 2 as shown in line 55, but I want the bombs to be set randomly.

The part of my game that deals with the AI's bombs:

```
import random

def bombs():
    for i in range(0,8):
        row = random.randint(1,8)
        column = random.randint(1,8)
        grid[row][column] = 2
        print(row,column)
        i = i+1
 
# Create a 2 dimensional array. A two dimensional array is simply a list of lists.
grid = []
for row in range(8):
    # Add an empty array that will hold each cell
    # in this row
    grid.append([])
    for column in range(0,8):
        grid[row].append(0)  # Append a cell
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hazza\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\CHECK.py", line 54, in <module>
    bombs()
  File "C:\Users\hazza\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\CHECK.py", line 9, in bombs
    grid[row][column] = 2
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Arrays are 0-indexed. Make sure your rng function returns at least 0 and less than array length.

Answer (score 2):

`random.randint(a, b)` generates a random integer *N* such that *a <= N <= b*. List indices start at 0.
Use [`random.randrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) to generate a random column and row in a specified range:

```py
row = random.randrange(8)
column = random.randrange(8)
grid[row][column] = 2
```

`random.randrange` works like [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range), but it doesn't generate a range, it just returns a random number in the specified range.

Answer (score 1):

Your `grid` has 8 items, with indices from 0 to 7 (zero based indexing). However, `random.randint(1,8)` takes random number from 1 to 8, including the boundary values. So if the random number is 8, you get this index out of range error (you can easily debug it with `print`ing the value before the line

Change it to

```py
row = random.randint(0,7) # column the same
```